# How to point to a specific location in a notebook?

Tags: notebooks, documentation

I am writing a very long code and I need to refer to some line of codes in comments to clarify the definitions.
Is there any way that I can refer to a line in a Notebook or create a hyperlink to take the viewer to the location of the definition?

Comment: Take a look at `CellTags` and `NotebookLocate`. Also, search for those names on MSE there are several similar questions/answers.